# I want to create a script to do 3 actions

Tags: python, scripting, interface, operator, workspaces

I'm working on creating and editing trees/leaves for a personal project. I want to create a button I can just press to do the following actions:

<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor to Selected*
<kbd>Right Mouse Button</kbd> *Set Origin > Origin to 3D Cursor*

And that's it. I'm doing some leaves using pivot painter and I need the origin and pivot to be in a specific way so imagine doing all this process for each leaf and a total of 500 leaves at least I have some sort of fast way. I'll just look for a tutorial on how to add that script to a button.

I already tried doing it myself but im a Zbrush user that only models and sculpt so this is a really hard thing for me. the codes I wrote don't even execute something in Blender

Comment: You could save the code as a .py file and upload it as an addon in blender through preferences > addons > Install

Comment: paste your 3 action in execute of the operator:  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/266491/how-to-select-a-collection-from-the-3d-viewport-by-right-clicking-on-one-of-the

Comment: Do i understand correctly that you want to set the origin of each leaf object to the same point (the tree)? Then the easiest is to set the origin once, then select all the leaves together (hold shift while selecting, or box-select in the outliner) and do the "set origin" once - no need to do this for each leaf object individually.

If you have a different origin for each leaf it's probably worth writing a little script to do it, since there is no real user input required.